# Given an array of Strings, words, return that array with all Strings of an even length replaced with an empty string

Tags: java, arrays, string

Given an array of Strings, words, return that array with all Strings of an even length replaced with an empty string.

```
blankAllEvens( { "Hi", "there", "bob" }) => {"", "there", "bob"}
blankAllEvens({ "this", "is", "sparta!"}) => {"", "", "sparta!"}
blankAllEvens({ }) => {}
```

How do I return the string? 
I need to return the string in order to print blank space for the evens but right now I am just returning a count.
This is my code I think everything is right, I just don't know how to return it?

```
public String[] blankAllEvens( String[] words ) {
 int cnt = 0;
  for (int i=0; i<words.length; i++) {
    if (words[i].substring(0, 1).equals("2")) {
  cnt++;
     }
  }
  return cnt; 
}
```

Comment: I'm sure `cnt` stands for count but that's not how I read it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
public String[] blankAllEvens( String[] words ) {
   for (int i=0; i <words.length; i++) {
      if (words[i].length() % 2 == 0) {
         words[i] = "";
      }
   }
   return words;
}
```

Basically, the if statement checks to see if the word in the array has an even length (we are dividing the word length by 2 and seeing if we get a remainder of 0);  In that case, we blank it.

Comment: I tried this and now it is saying that it can not find symbol cannot find symbol
      if (words[i].length % 2 == 0) {
                  ^
  symbol:   variable length
  location: class String

Comment: I've updated the above code.  The if statement should be  if(words[i].length() % 2 == 0) {